# Can i use google Places API in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have written an java application that uses Google Places Api (i added the api as an external library in Eclipse). I am able able to get places in a given radius. My project is not desktop based though, it should be an android phone based. Can i import the Google map api in Android SDK? How do i do that? It's gicing me errors when i try to add the API as external libraries to my android project.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need [registration](http://gmaps-ws-console.appspot.com/) and the [Maps API key](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/06/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key/)

There are tutorials dedicated to this :
 - [Part 1](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/) & [2](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-2-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/) on how to use Places API

Comment: I have read those tutorial, the writer leaves my question answered as "coming soon" on part 3.

Comment: [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/ddewaele/GooglePlacesApi) that you may use. You might need [this jar](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android)